# Date in Pandas transformating

Tags: python, pandas, date, data-analysis

There is information about holding promotions in stores, for example, a promotion in store №1 for product №3 starts on 05.04.2022 and ends on 08.04.2022. How to display all the days of the promotion, in this case 05.04.2022, 06.04.2022, 07.04.2022, 08.04.2022. For a better understanding of the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0QqT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: combine `pd.date_range` to create the dates, then `explode`

Comment: @mozway, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @AndriiKrush please read in detail the linked duplicate, if you don't manage, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72098991/edit) your question to provide a minimal reproducible example as input, the code that you have tested and how it fails. I'm am subscribing to the question to be informed when you make edits.